# Added 2BG of RAM to my laptop’s 8GB but Windows 10 (64bit) only sees 8GB and does not see the full 10GB as physical memory

Tags: memory, ddr3

I installed 2GB of RAM into my new laptop (Acer Aspire E5-571-5688), which used to be in my old broken laptop. This would make my total RAM into 10GB (1x8GB + 1x2GB). My problem is that Windows 10 (64-bit) install doesn’t seem to recognize or use my new RAM.

I ran a memory diagnostic test and I’ve checked with [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html). CPU-Z gave me a result saying there is 10GB, however Windows doesn’t. I entered `systeminfo` into the elevated cmd, this gave me the result saying I have 10GB of virtual memory, 8GB of physical memory of which 5.671MB is available. It also says Virtual memory in use: 2.478MB.

The 2GB of RAM I’ve installed isn’t the same brand as the 8GB of RAM, but according to some forums that didn't make any difference.

According to CPU-Z the 8GB RAM max running speed is at 800MHz, as is the current NB Frequency. The 2GB SoDIMM is running at 667MHz. Would it maybe help to change the RAM speed to 1333 or should it still stay 1600 (as I assume it is now).

Sorry I couldn’t include screenshots.

Comment: run msconfig.exe and make sure you don't limit the RAM to 8GB

Comment: I already did. I switched max memory off.

Answer (score 0):

Are you useing the right amount ram modules in equal proportions as you can't add a 1gb ram modules with 2gb ram modules together,the ram modules have to be of equal proportion to make a 10gb ram work,you can't add uneven modules,you have to use 5 X 2g ram modules. I found this out on the XDA forum so have a look there you might find a full explanation I am in no way an expert in this area it is just something I read on RAM modules and how they work I hope this helps a little towards solving your problems

Comment: That must eb a specifix thing then for that model only. The rest of the world can happily mix 1GB, 2GB and other sizes of DIMMs without problems. Just do not expect multi channel mode, so no extra 5%-ish speed boost. But it does work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)